# postgresql jsonb - from list of integers to list of Objects

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a question regarding jsonb in postgresql.

I have a table that has a column of type jsonb, where I store a list of integers.

For example **list_integers** column:
**[1, 2, 3, 4]**

I want to add a new column in this table, and insert in this column the same IDs, but the form would be list of objects, where the ID field corresponds to the integer.

For example **list_ids** column:
**[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}]**

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to save `{"id": [1, 2, 3, 4]}`?

Comment: actually, I'm making the change because more information will need to be saved by Id, for example:

[{"id": 1, "alias": "alias1"}, {"id": 2, "foo": "asd"}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}]

Answer (score 1):

To transform:

````sql
test=> SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', id))
test-> FROM   jsonb_array_elements(jsonb '[1, 2, 3, 4]') id;
                  jsonb_agg                   
----------------------------------------------
 [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}]
(1 row)```
````